# I am having trouble with my Formik and CK editor to call my POST API

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I am having trouble with my Formik and CK editor to call my POST API. This is what I tried and it was not working for me. Is there anyway that I can try?I was supposed to use the setFormField function but I was not sure how to use it in there.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import toastr from 'toastr';
import blogSchema from './blogSchema';
import DisplayImage from './DisplayImage';
import blogService from '../../services/blogService';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import debug from 'sabio-debug';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

const _logger = debug.extend("BlogsFormAddEdit");

function BlogsFormAddEdit() {

  const [addEditFormData] = useState({

    authorId: "",
    title: "",
    content: "",

  });

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    _logger(values);
    debugger;
    blogService
      .getAddBlog(values)
      .then(onAddSuccess)
      .catch(onAddError)
  }

  const onAddSuccess = (response) => {
    _logger(response);
    toastr.success("Your blog has posted", "Adding Success")
  }

  const onAddError = (err) => {
    _logger(err);
    toastr.error("Your blog failed to post", "Adding Failure")
  }



  return (
    <React.Fragment>

      <Formik
        enableReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={addEditFormData}
        validationSchema={blogSchema}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}

      >
        <Form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <h1>Blog Add/Edit Form</h1>
            <label htmlFor="authorId">Author Id</label>
            <Field type="text" name="authorId" className="form-control"

            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
            <Field type="text" name="title" className="form-control"

            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">

            <label htmlFor="content">Content</label>
            <CKEditor
              editor={ClassicEditor}
              onChange={(event, editor) => {
                const data = editor.getData();
                _logger({ event, editor, data });
              }}

            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>


        </Form>
      </Formik>
      <DisplayImage />
      <img alt="" src={addEditFormData} />

    </React.Fragment >

  )
}

export default BlogsFormAddEdit;
```

That's what I tried and my content was not really working with the CK editor

Comment: You need to bind it to formik. How to do it is here http://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/issues/205 but note it appears problematic. Are you tied strongly to CKEditor? Since it has issues (and is pretty old school) you might consider https://www.slatejs.org/. React bindings: https://docs.slatejs.org/libraries/slate-react

Comment: Then again the issue on github is old. Might be ok now. The code in the top post is on the right tracks. `Field` is from formik.